# Close modal button doesn't work in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add this modal to my existing HTML page.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="height: 100vh !important">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 100vh; opacity:1">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  >&times;</button>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                  <li><a href="#myPage">HOME1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="bg-img-hero">
     <nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myModal">
              <span class="icon-bar" style="color: yellow !important"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
              </button>
              <img src="Images\logos\flexit-logo-TM-comp.png" style="padding-top:15px" >  
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                 <li ><a href="HowItWorks.html" style="color: white !important">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band" style="color: white !important">BAND</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour" style="color: white !important">TOUR</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact" style="color: white !important">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md" >
                 <li><a href="HowItWorks.html">HOME1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#band">BAND1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#tour">TOUR1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>

        </div>
     </nav>
  </div>
```

The above modal works fine in the W3schools demo, but when added to my code, the "Close Modal" is not working. I am not able to figure out why. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What isn't working ? You can't see the whole modal or only the close button that doesn't work like it is written in the title ?

Comment: Hi @Eudz, I am able to see the entire, except my close modal button is not working. I am not able to close the modal.

Comment: Actually I notice that none of the button in My modal works, Like I have few buttons added to the modal, But none of them works

Comment: @Eudz I have updated the exact code, Please check out and let me know if you could identify the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to have put `data-toggle="modal"` on the button that is supposed to open the modal.

Comment: I have updated the exact code, Please check out and let me know if you could identify the mistake

Answer (score -1):

check the console of your browser if it shows any error give us an error to resolve but might possible that it should be an error of Jquery or $() is not a function that will mean u havn't included the require jquery or you are not using the correct version of bottstrap javascript

Comment: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" is the error I am getting console. Can this be the reason?